# Crear query en un repositorio en spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Tengo un repositorio y en su interface quiero crear una función que me solicite un String y me devuelva un objeto de tipo usuario, en mysql la sintaxis seria así :

```
SELECT C.NOMBRE FROM CLIENTE C, ALIAS A WHERE A.NOMBRE = 'bar' AND A.CLIENTE_ID = C.ID
```

sin embargo, ¿Como seria en la interface?

esta es mi clase:

```
package app.core.repository;

import app.core.entity.Cliente;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer>{

@Query("SELECT Cliente FROM CLIENTE, ALIAS A WHERE A.NOMBRE = 'bar' AND A.CLIENTE_ID = C.ID")
Cliente getClientePorAlias(@Param("alias") String alias);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente mi función quedo así:

```
@Query("SELECT A.cliente FROM Alias A WHERE lower(A.nombre) = lower(:alias)")
Cliente findClienteByAlias(@Param("alias") String alias);
```

Comment: Como hago si en su caso en lugar de recibir un solo usuario quiero recibir una lista de usuarios

Answer (score 0):

Con Spring Data JPA sería así:

```
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer>{

@Query("SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nombre= :alias AND c.cliente_id= :id")
Cliente getClientePorAlias(@Param("alias") String alias,@Param("id")Integer id);

}
```